What are the prohibitions against certain kinds of aliasing through unions?
In the C standard (specifically, n3220, ie. the latest working draft of C23), which paragraphs would make the following code examples invoke undefined behaviour?:
void f(int *a, char *b) {
  (*a)++;
  *a += *b;
}

int main() {
  union u {
    int a;
    char b;
  } x;
  x.a = 1;
  f(&x.a, &x.b);
}

union u {
  int a;
  char b;
};

void f(int *a, union u *x) {
  (*a)++;
  *a += x->b;
}

int main() {
  union u x;
  x.a = 1;
  f(&x.a, &x);
}

For the first example:
I have read through the standard, and it seems that everything up to the function call should be strictly conformant to the standard, and that there should be a problem with accessing the object representation of a union with l-values of incompatible type where the l-values cannot be traced back to the given union. Or perhaps is the restriction that "type punning" (as referred to by footnote 93) only works when the l-value is the direct result of the . operator? This would be the case if the term "member" in footnote 93 is taken to not be referring to the associated member object; but the standard is not (to my knowledge) very clear about any such distinction. 6.5.1p7 might also support this conclusion since it talks about accessing the stored value, but then that would seem to contradict footnote 93 (since it would seem to prohibit type punning under all circumstances).
For the second example: If the latter reason given above is true, then, what would make this example invoke undefined behaviour? Or would it be strictly conformant, requiring the compiler assume that the union object representation may be aliased by the int *?

Depending on endianness, the location of b in the union memory might not be what you expect. That means (void *) &x.a != (void *) &x.b might be true., which means the value of x.b is indeterminate (it could be either 1 or 0).

@Someprogrammerdude, consider 6.7.3.2p18:
"The members of a union object overlap in such a way that pointers to them when converted to pointers to character type point to the same byte."
Given that void * and char * have the same alignment requirements, this guarantees that (void *)&x.a == (void *)&x.b. Also, the value read by x.b must not be indeterminate, since character types have no padding bits - though it needn't have a value of either 0 or 1.

I'm wrong about the pointers (sorry for that), but not about the endianness issue. The bytes of a might be either 0 0 0 1 or 1 0 0 0 (assuming a 32-bit int type). So b will be either 0 or 1 (assuming 8-bit char type).

@chux I had not thought about overflow due to signed addition, but it is a good point that it could cause UB: x->b could read as 0 or SCHAR_MIN or 2^n for 0 <= n < CHAR_BIT, or other things too due to padding bits being set, and a char could be wide enough for this to cause issues (at least 16 bits). Also, you say "due to overlap", UB occurs, but which part of the specification actually says this?

@Someprogrammerdude that is assuming 8-bit chars though, and also, the standard does not specify the order of bits w.r.t. significance (eg. the 2^15 bit could immediately follow the 2^1 bit). Plus, padding bits could also be set, and all in all it's not really possible to tell anything about what x.b equals without implementation specifics.

@chux to be exact, something like *a += *a is valid. Something like x.a += x.b should, it appears, also be valid (it would be surprising were it not, and also a bit tangential to the actual issue). The fact that aliasing occurs is not the issue, but that it in essence sneaks around the strict aliasing rules by accessing different objects that just happen to have overlapping object representation, in a way such that the compiler can't see that the object representations overlap.

@chux f(&x, &x) is perfectly allowable. The formal parameters corresponding to each of the arguments would require at least one declared with the restrict qualifier to invoke UB. Actually, to be exact, it would require not only that, but also that the pointers are used to perform an access in such a way as is prohibited by the restrict semantics. Or it would otherwise require breaking the strict aliasing rule, or doing something else to generate UB.

As a specific common example, we have memcpy vs memmove.

@chux "compiler can assume a and b point to non-overlapping memory" Compiler cannot assume that. b is char *, and character type is an exception in aliasing rules. Situation would be different if b was short* or float*.

@chux memcpy does have restrict.

@chux 7.26.2.1p1. memcpy has the prototype void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n);. The restrict keyword being there is exactly why memcpy must not be passed pointers to overlapping objects.

@user694733 that's actually a quite important note... I will edit the question since in reality, due to that, there is no UB.

I have added to _Atomic qualifier to the char types, but upon inspection, a strict aliasing exception still occurs...

There are no strict aliasing problems before or after the edit.

I have fixed it now, so that char * is now unsigned int *, and there should now be no exception to the strict aliasing rules.

Also kindly stop changing the question when there are answers present. Constantly "moving the goal posts" is not OK. If you have a different question than the original one, then please ask it separately once there are posted answers. I did a rollback of edits.

And again, none of the 3 versions you posted have any strict aliasing problems...

@ThomasP66 Yes, agree about memcpy().  Simply too tired last night.  Comment cleaner came through.

Both examples are undefined behavior since the memory locations overlap. None of that is related to strict aliasing. It is UB as per C23 6.5.17.2:

If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way the storage
of the first object, then the two objects shall occupy exactly the same storage and shall have qualified
or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.


Furthermore it may also cause problems in case the representations do not match. char may or may not be unsigned, and may or may not overwrite the sign bit of the int. Not really UB but implementation-defined behavior, both in terms of signedness of char as well as endianness. There's also potentially unspecified behavior as per 6.2.6.1:
[Normative text]

Where an operator is applied to a value that has more than one object representation, which object representation is used shall not affect the value of the result.44) Where a value is stored in an object
using a type that has more than one object representation for that value, it is unspecified which representation is used, but a non-value representation shall not be generated.

[Informative foot note:]

44) It is possible for objects x and y with the same effective type T to have the same value when they are accessed as objects
of type T, but to have different values in other contexts. In particular, if == is defined for type T, then x == y does not imply
that memcmp(&x, &y, sizeof(T))== 0. Furthermore, x == y does not necessarily imply that x and y have the same value;
other operations on values of type T can distinguish between them.


But there aren't really any concerns about strict aliasing since no effective type is referred to through an incorrect lvalue access. Futhermore, an int* and a char* alias: the compiler cannot assume that a modification to what the int* pointed at didn't result in an update of what the char* pointed at and vice versa. This is because a char* may point at any object.
(Also, a union that include a compatible type of the effective type of the object may be used to lvalue access said object, as far as strict aliasing is concerned. Doesn't apply to these examples.)
However, accessing a char[] through a de-referenced int* would be a strict aliasing violation and possibly also a misaligned access.
Specifically:

and that there should be a problem with accessing the object representation of a union with l-values of incompatible type where the l-values cannot be traced back to the given union

As per the quote from 6.2.6.1, there could be multiple object representations here and the requirement is that at least one should be valid. Whether it can get "traced back" or not doesn't matter, what matters is which effective type the actual data got. In this case int and char both, at the same time.

I fixed the issue with int * and char * aliasing now by using unsigned int *.

@ThomasP66 Read my comments below the question.

Yes, I saw it, that's why I pointed it out. If I may ask, though, in the following case, what issues would there be to cause UB?:
void f(int *a, unsigned int *b) { (*a)++; unsigned int c = *b; *a += c; }
int main() { union u { int a; unsigned int b; } x; x.a = 1; f(&x.a, &x.b); }

I apologise for the poor formatting; in essence, unsigned int rather than char for b, and copying to a separate unsigned int before the assignment statement. Would it be invalid? Or would it be well-defined behaviour?

@ThomasP66 Same UB as in the original question: assignment that overlaps. int and unsigned int occupy the same space, they alias, but they are not compatible types.

In the given case, however, the access to *b, which is in int c = *b; is not part of the assignment expression, *a += c;, so 6.5.17.2p3 does not apply. Actually, 6.5.17.2p3 doesn't appear to apply in the original case either, since it applies specifically to the = operator, and not any of the compound assignment operators.

Granted, given the exceptions to the strict aliasing rule, and given 6.5.17.2p3 not applying since the assignment is compound, it does appear that the specific case in the question should yield well-defined behaviour (ignoring possible edge cases relating to the width and representation of the char and int type being such that overflow occurs).

@ThomasP66 Hmm ok yeah in that example they don't overlap due to the temp variable. So that example is well-defined. *a will get modified, the compiler cannot assume that b is not an alias of a so it has to reload *b from memory. Compound assignment or not doesn't matter. Compound assignment semantics go: "A compound assignment of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to the simple assignment expression..."

@ThomasP66 Had you restrict qualified both pointers in the function though but kept the rest of the code as-is, then it would be UB due to the programmer violating the restrict contract. Because in that case the compiler could assume that (*a)++ did not modify what b points at.

The specific wording of 6.5.17.2p3 refers specifically to the "value stored" being "read from another object" which would seem not to be the case here; the value stored is (afaict) not the same as the value read from *b, but in fact differs from it by having *a added to it. Actually, the wording is a little unclear to me; I'm not sure what the purpose is, to be exact, unless it perhaps is referring to an assignment like *a = *b would be, except a type conversion would render the value stored to *a different to the value read from *b, I believe...

I don't think there was ever any consensus understanding about how unions were supposed to interact with the Effective Type Rule, especially given that C99 TC3 explicitly defines the behavior of writing one union member and reading another.

@ThomasP66: I think the intention is that (1) in general, an unsequenced read and write of the same storage would invoke UB; (2) if lvalues of compatible type are used to access the same storage on both sides of an assignment operator, actions that read a portion fo an object's value will be sequenced before actions that write that portion of the value, but unsequenced with regard to actions that access other portions of the value.

Defect Report 028 indicates that passing the addresses of two members of the same union into a function which uses them both to access the same storage should be treated as UB, but fails to identify anything in the Standard that would cause it not to be have implementation-defined behavior in the same scenarios where an action on the union type would do likewise.  Given e.g.
union U { T1 m1; T2 m2; } u;
T1 test1(T1 *dummy1, T1 v1, T2 *dummy2, T2 v2)
{
  u.m1 = v1;
  u.m2 = v2;
  return *p1;
}
T1 test2(T1 *p1, T1 v1, T2 *p2, T2 v2)
{
  *p1 = v1;
  *p2 = v2;
  return *p1;
}

the C89 Standard would characterize test1 as invoking Implementation-Define Behavior, and C99 actually goes further and defines the behavior.  In the scenario where p1 equals &u.m1 and p2 equals &u.m2, neither C89 and C99 identifies anything about test2() that would suggest it shouldn't be equivalent to test1(), but DR 028 says that because writing one union member and reading another invokes Implementation-Defined Behavior, doing so through pointers invokes Undefined Behavior.
The characterization of UB could have been justified if DR 028 had observed that there is no general permission to access union objects (or structures, for that matter) via lvalues of member type, but that the "Strict Aliasing Rule" presumed that implementations would treat an lvalue that was freshly visibly derived from something of some type T as being usable to access anything that could be accessed as type T, and that implementations were intended to refrain from imposing needless restrictions.  Under such an interpretation, test1 would have Implementation Defined behavior because each lvalue used for access would be freshly visibly derived from u, but test2 would invoke UB because the pointers would not be freshly visibly derived from u.  If instead the usage pattern had been something like:
T1 read_t1(T1 *p) { return *p; }
void write_t1(T1 *p, T1 v) { *p = v; }
void write_t2(T2 *p, T2 v) { *p = v; }
T1 test3(T1 *dummy1, T1 v1, T2 *dummy2, T2 v2)
{
  write_t1(&u.v1);
  write_t2(&u.v2);
  return read_t1(&u.v1);
}

then behavior should be treated as defined because a compiler would have no reason to care about whether the store in write_t2 could interact with the load in read_t1 unless it could see everything that happened between the store in write_t1 and the load in read_t1, and a a compiler that could see those things would also see that all three accesses are using lvalues that are freshly visibly derived from an object of type union U.
If the Standard had clarified the intention that compilers not be willfully blind to situations where an lvalue of one type is freshly visibly derived from another, then the finding in DR 028 would be entirely justifiable, but many behaviors of clang and gcc would not.  As it is, the Standard has evolved to be self-contradictory, simultaneously specifying that some actions are equivalent to others whose behavior is expressly defined, and characterizing those same actions as UB.  The only way to avoid contradiction is to recognize that the Standard doesn't grant general permission to use member-type lvalues to access struct or union objects, but instead relies on a quality-of-implementation-dependent ability of implementations to recognize when lvalues are freshly visibly derived from others.
